# Definir array com dados de "ComboBox" select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

1. O utilizador escolhe um valor na *comboBox* select2.
2. Clica em "GUARDAR" e essa *combobox* Select2 deveria ser guardada
   num array com os eventos definidos.
3. Após isto voltaria ao ponto 1, não alterando os dados previamente
   guardados.

Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Poderia postar algum código já criado, alguma tentativa?

Comment: você não precisa de algo como um multi select?https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?ji8YG4nk

Comment: O objectivo não é ter um multi-select.
Mas sim fazer algo do genero:
HTML:
<select id="teste"></select>
Jquery/Javascript
var x=[];
x.push($("#teste").select2({ajax:....});)
Agora queria fazer outra combo diferente mas no mesmo select
x.push($("#teste").select2({ajax:....});)

Isto porque eu depois preciso de mostrar os dois selects, lado a lado, com os valores escolhidos pelo utilizador em cada um.

Comment: Conseguiram perceber o que eu precisava?